# Nutch 2.x run every URL every time

Tags: nutch

In Nutch 2.2.1, when I run Nutch every time, it will crawl all URLs include I have already crawled. I want one URL only to be crawled one time no matter how many times Nutch runs. How can I configure it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fetching a website, Nutch marks the URL of the website as a FETCHED URL, and it will not crawl the URL again in the next crawling round. By default, Nutch will re-crawl after 30 days. You can change the default number of seconds between re-fetches of a page by modifying the **db.fetch.interval.default** property.

Hope this helps,

Le Quoc Do

Comment: but i use mysql, i see two columns in table webpage:fetchtime and prevfetchtime ,every time i re-crawl the website, this two fields will change...